# What are the requirements for a server serving mpeg-dash

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I am trying to understand if I can serve mpeg dash from normal blog storage.

I have created a test cases using the Youtube MPEG-DASH - Media Source Demo.

The example they give works

http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html?url=http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-manifest.mpd

But when I try and host the same files within an Azure website I get the following error.

http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html?url=http://videostreamtest.azurewebsites.net/mpegdash/car-20120827-manifest.mpd

`3, Implausible duration from video element: NaN`

**Can anyone tell me what the requirements are for hosting mpeg dash are and why I am getting the error I am getting?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have wrong CORS settings on our webserver, as the range request is causing an error, just look in your console and you will see "Request header field Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.". Did you enable CORS?

You can go for segmented MPEG-DASH content, where no "range" header field is necessary. you could transcode some from [bitcodin.com](http://www.bitcodin.com) and put it on your webserver with an MPEG-DASH player such as [dash-player.com](http://www.dash-player.com).

Comment: Putting the `range` as a `GET` parameter is also allowed by MPEG-DASH.  The CDN will have to support that, of course.